# Grails Sql Server Express

Tags: grails, datasource, sql-server-express

I would like some help about setting Grails to work with SQL Server Express. I know I have to change the datasource, but I'm not sure exactly what to do, and couldn't find updated information on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the datasource settings in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`

```
dataSource {

    // Change the values of these properties to the username, password and hostname
    // for your SQL Server database
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=your_database_name_here"

    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
}
```

You'll need to make sure that the SQL Server JDBC driver is on your classpath either by copying it to the `lib` directory of the grails application, or configuring it as a runtime dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: ps: i found this tutorial: http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/01/setting-up-sql-server-2008-express-to.html. Is it this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to specify different database settings for different environemnts? If so, post it as a separate question and I'll answer it

Comment: no. im talking about the environment like for example when im developing. It will use the in-memory GORM and not my sql database right?